# Handling separate async calls for items in Redux store

Tags: asynchronous, redux

I have some racing bees. In my redux store, they are objects in an array with a name property and a likelihood property. For each bee, I would like to calculate its likelihood of winning. The calculating algorithm is async. When I start the calculations of all the bees, the bee's likelihood property should have a value of 'calculating', when the bee's calculation has completed, the likelihood property should show a number.

I have a function `generateBeeWinLikelihoodCalculator` which cannot be modified.

Right now, my code does not calculate the likelihood of winning for the bees separately and I am at a loss for how best to achieve this. I thought of dispatching the calcultingLikelihood function to each bee instance and calling it in the reducer, but then how do I get it to return 'calculating...' first and then when the setTimeout has run, to then return the value?

```js
let state = {bees:[{name: 'marie'},{name: 'john'}]}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
   case 'FETCH_BEES':
     return {
       ...state,
        bees: action.bees,
      }
    case 'RUN_CALCULATIONS':
     return {
       ...state,
        bees: state.bees.map(bee => {
         bee.likelihood = action.likelihood
          return bee
        })
      }
     case 'DISPLAY_CALCULATIONS':
      return {
       ...state,
        bees: state.bees.map(bee => {
         bee.likelihood = action.likelihood
          return bee
        })
      }
     default: return state
  }
}

const runCalculations = (likelihood) => ({
 type: 'RUN_CALCULATIONS',
  likelihood,
})

const displayCalculations = (likelihood) => ({
 type: 'DISPLAY_CALCULATIONS',
  likelihood,
})

const store = {
 dispatch: (action) => {
   state = reducer(state,action)
   return state
  },
  getState: () => {
   return state
  }
}

//this calculator cannot be modified
const generateBeeWinLikelihoodCalculator = () => {
  var delay = 1000 + Math.random() * 1000;
  var likelihoodOfAntWinning = Math.random();

  return function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback(likelihoodOfAntWinning)
    }, delay);
  };
}

const calculatingLikelihood = () => {
  store.dispatch(runCalculations('calculating...'))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(store.getState()))
 const callback = (likelihoodOfBeeWinning) => {
   store.dispatch(displayCalculations(likelihoodOfBeeWinning))
   console.log(JSON.stringify(store.getState()))
  }
  return generateBeeWinLikelihoodCalculator()(callback)
}

calculatingLikelihood()
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: You have a list of objects. With each individual object (bee) you need  to perform some asynchronous work and update that object in state once the work has resolved?

You could wait for all work promises to resolve before updating state or you can update state for each resolved calculation individually

Comment: I need to update the state of each resolved calculation, but I am currently at a loss for how to do the calculations separately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the bees an id property as well and store them as a map of bees by id vs. an array of bees. This makes updating individual bees in state easier.

You can make use of promises or async/await as well.

So state becomes:

let state = {bees: { 1: { id: 1, name: 'marie' }, 2: { id: 2 name: 'john'} }

```
// Grab the list of Bees
const bees = store.getState().bees

// Work on each bee and update it individually
Object.values(bees).forEach(async bee => {
  const likelihood = await calculate(bee)
  store.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_BEE', payload: { ...bee, likelihood } })
})

// Or you could wait for all calculations to resolve before updating state
const promises = Object.values(bees).map(async bee => {
  const likelihood = await calculate(bee)
  return { ...bee, likelihood }
})

Promise.all(promises).then(bees => {
  store.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_BEES', payload: _.keyBy(bees, 'id') })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to show the likelihood figure as each figure resolves. I can't wait for the first bee to resolve before dispatching the action for the next bee. They have to run simultaneously and if calculations for bee 3 resolve first, then it is shown first.

Comment: That is exactly what it is doing in the `forEach` loop. The function passed to `forEach` is an asynchronous function. The iteration won't wait for the calculation promise to resolve before moving on to the next one.